# Inspect pixel color on screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to determine the color of something on my screen that is part of my app, such as the background color of an activity. The only solution I can think of is to take a snapshot of the screen and then inspect it with a graphics app. Is there something built into Android or Android Studio that lets me inspect the color of something on the screen to determine it's RGB value?

NOTE: This is strictly for debugging my app. I don't need something to integrate into my app. I need a tool to verify what the colors are on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib to obtain color from view in RGB (`"#" + envelope.getHexCode()`): https://github.com/skydoves/ColorPickerView

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for something to integrate into my app. I just need a tool for development to tell me what the pixel color is on screen. If it works for any app that is running, that is great. But if it only works for my app, that is fine too.